# Basic Pointer C Programming

Tags: c, pointers

Hey I'm trying to switch the two parameters around only when parameter 1 is greater than parameter 2.

What I've got so far is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ascending2(int*, int*);

int main(void){
    int ptr1 = 20;
    int ptr2 = 10;
    printf("ptr1 = %d, ptr2 = %d", ascending2(&ptr1, &ptr2));
    return 0;
}

void ascending2(int *ptr1, int* ptr2){
    int *value; 
    if( *ptr1 >= *ptr2 ){
         *value = *ptr1;
         *ptr1 = *ptr2;
         *ptr2 = *value;}
}
```

Can anyone suggest where I may be going wrong, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem really is.

Comment: Not a bug, but the variable names `ptr1` and `ptr2` in `main()` are really bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because in the `ascending2` function you declare `value` as a pointer, but you don't actually make it point anywhere. So when you dereference it you dereference an uninitialized pointer which leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

There are two obvious solutions: Either you make `value` point somewhere valid, or even better you declare it as a non-pointer variable.

---

There also the problem with your `printf` call, as `ascending2` is declared to return `void`, in other words it doesn't return anything at all, and yet you print two values. This will also lead to undefined behavior.

The solution here is to call the function separately, and then call `printf` with the `ptr1` and `ptr2` variables (which by the way are not very well named, as they are not actually pointers).

Answer (score 2):

```
printf("ptr1 = %d, ptr2 = %d", ascending2(&ptr1, &ptr2));
```

here `ascending2(..)` not returning anything.
Require to change `printf`. like

```
 ascending2(&ptr1, &ptr2);
 printf("ptr1 = %d, ptr2 = %d",ptr1,ptr2);
```

And your function should be

```
void ascending2(int *ptr1, int* ptr2){
    int value;                     // change *value to value
    if( *ptr1 >= *ptr2 ){
         value = *ptr1;            // change *value to value
         *ptr1 = *ptr2;
         *ptr2 = value;}           // change *value to value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `value` you declare is a pointer. Change it to `int value`.

Answer (score 1):

Here, the mistakes are corrected.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ascending2(int*, int*);

int main(void){
    int ptr1 = 20;
    int ptr2 = 10;
    ascending2(&ptr1, &ptr2); //Fix1

    printf("ptr1 = %d, ptr2 = %d", ptr1, ptr2);
    return 0;
}

void ascending2(int *ptr1, int* ptr2){
    int value=0; //Fix2
    if( *ptr1 >= *ptr2 ){
         value = *ptr1;
         *ptr1 = *ptr2;
         *ptr2 = value;}
}
```

Fix1:
Argument should not be passed to `printf` statement as you did.The function ascending2  also not returning any values. So call ascending2 API 1st and then print the values of ptr1, ptr2. To know more about `printf` please refer the below link.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Fix2:

Inside ascending2 function no need to use `value` as a pointer variable. It can be just integer. If you use `value` as pointer, then proper memory should be provided.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add some suggestions, there are already good answers: the swap function can be improved:

```
void ascending2(int *ptr1, int* ptr2)
{
  if( *ptr1 > *ptr2 )
  {
    const int tmp = *ptr1;
    *ptr1 = *ptr2;
    *ptr2 = tmp;
  }
}
```

The improvements:

- Use `>` for the comparison, there's no need to do anything if the two values are equal so comparing using `>=` makes no sense.
- Moved the temporary variable into the scope where it's used.
- Renamed it to `tmp` to make it a bit clearer what it does. "Value" is really generic.
- Made it `const` since it doesn't change after being assigned.
- Initialize directly with the desired value.

Comment: Thanks, what does 'tmp' stand for?

Comment: @IamTrent It's a commonly used contraction of "temporary".